# Is it appropriate to estimate a random slope without estimating the overall mean slope?

Tags: mixed-model, lme4-nlme, stan

I am trying to estimate whether there are differences in how individuals in different cities (my grouping variable) respond to a few predictor variables. So, in practice, I am interested in learning about the $\beta$s from each city. But, I want to use random slopes so that these estimates are "shrunk" towards some group mean.

I am fitting my model using `stan_glmer` from the `stanarm` package, which accepts input in the same way as `glmer` from `lme4`.

So, question #1. If I don't care about the grand slope, is it ok to specify the model like this:

```
stan_glmer(Y ~ (V1 + V2 + V3|city))
```

Or do I need to include V1, V2, V3 as "fixed effects" first? e.g.

```
stan_glmer(Y ~ V1 + V2 + V3 + (V1 + V2 + V3|city))
```

Secondly, if the second model is the correct option (which I somewhat suspect), then how do I interpret the output? In order to get an estimate for the slope of V1 in city 1, do I add the overall $\beta_{v1}$ to city 1's $\beta_{v1}$? How do you account for error in that case?

Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Fitting random slopes with the population-level slope fixed to zero is not out of the question - it's not mathematically or statistically ill-posed - but it's a rather weird model that would require some extra justification. Why would you expect that the average slope across cities would be *exactly* zero (which is what is implied by the model that omits the fixed effect)? The only cases where I've seen fitting such models make sense are

- as a(n) (admittedly silly) null model, for doing a likelihood-ratio test of the significance of the population-level slope [not relevant in your case as you're using Bayesian methods]
- in cases where the effect is zero based on the experimental design, e.g. when samples are randomly assigned to test and treatment conditions in a pre-treatment condition (this would be eliminating a fixed effect of treatment in the "before" period, not a fixed slope, but the idea is similar).

If you have a fixed-effect slope and among-city variation in the slope, you do indeed need to add the population-level slope to the individual-city slope deviation, and use the posterior distribution of the sum for inference - I don't know exactly how this is done in `rstanarm` ([related](https://discourse.mc-stan.org/t/extracting-overall-coefficient-estimates-from-rstanarm/2243/2)) ... the `tidybayes` package might help.

Comment: Thanks @Ben. I was working towards the understanding that the first model would be forcing that group slope to be zero, which, as you say, is not what I want. I'll look into whether `rstanarm` or `tidyverse` can generate calculated quantities for me and interpret those.